# XPS 13 9350 Bluetooth reception poor

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 19.04, broadcom, xps

This is potentially an hardware/antenna issue but just on the off-chance that someone knows anything about it being an issue on Ubuntu Linux, here's my question anyway.

Bluetooth reception on my XPS 13 (9350) seems extremely poor under Ubuntu Linux 19.10 (I don't know about Windows - haven't got it).

My bluetooth keyboard literally needs to be within 2 cm of the laptop or it won't work. Sometimes I even have to lift the keyboard to send the keystrokes I just made. Needless to say, it's impossible to work with this.

I've already tried copying the broadcom firmware from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM4350C5-0a5c-6412.hcd (this corresponded to the ID from `lsusb`) to `/lib/firmware/brcm/` and rebooted but this didn't help.

The keyboard works fine with other computers (Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was faster than expected. Turns out I had to perform a second step after copying the firmware. It has the wrong filename, so renaming BCM4350-0a5c-6412.hcd to BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd solved the problem for the most part.

Reception on my Bluetooth keyboard now seems good (as in it receives the keystrokes and no longer drops any). For the MX 720 Triathlon mouse, however, the Logitech Unifying received still performs a lot better than Bluetooth, which seems to drop a lot of information.

This was solved with a command found at the ArchLinux Forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1857256#p1857256

Running
`sudo /usr/bin/hcitool lecup --handle 64 --min 6 --max 7 --latency 0` made the mouse movements smooth as butter!